# MYSQL UPDATE date field not working

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update

Why won't this work:

```
USE presentations_db; UPDATE presentations_tbl SET `date` = '2012-12-13' WHERE `date` = '2013-12-12'
```

I have tried everywhere I could and can't find an answer.

date is the field name so used `back ticks` as required. date is of DATE data type.

Comment: *won't work* is not a valid MySQL error message.

Comment: Are you calling it from a PHP script or something similar?  If so, it's possible that the code handling your connection can't handle multiple queries.  As long as you're sure the DB is already set when the connection is made, you can get rid of that first part and only do the UPDATE statement.

Comment: sorry. There is no error message. It just doesn't run.

Comment: I am running it in workbench without php.

Comment: workbench does return messages. The update seems correct. Why don't you try it out without the USE statement. It should work anyways...

Comment: thanks koriander. Although I tried it without USE and it still wont update. I am new to workbench. Where will I see the messages?

Comment: ok. I managed to find the message. The status bar shows 'Query interrupted'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to run through the commandline. I clicked on "command line client" and it asked for a password. I then ran the sql statement and got the following result:

```
mysql> UPDATE `presentations_db`.`presentations_tbl`SET date_ = '2012-12-13' WHERE date_ = '2013-12-12';
Query OK, 16 rows affected (0.06 sec) Rows matched: 16 Changed: 16 Warnings: 0
```

When I tried to run the same query by simply running mysql though a shell it came up with an error that the db can not be edited by localhost, which is more explanatory than 'Query interrupted'. This seems to be a gripe previously covered in http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67766.
It would be nice if somone can tell me what I am doing wrong in workbench gui. I normally do the following when trying to run queries. I click on 'Edit Table Data' and the select the database and tables. It seems like I can view and run select queries but not update queries.